# Ubuntu 18.04 how to show date in top bar

Tags: 18.04, date

In my top bar, only the time is shown. How can I also see the date there?

Comment: Is it not included in ubuntu to show the date without installing new software? This is very surprising and a step back, as it is a very basic feature and older versions were able to do so... It will probably solve my question, just want to get sure that there is no easier way?

Comment: Normally when you install vanilla Gnome you get the tweak tool installed by default, just in canonicals spin off of gnome 3 you have to install it manually.

Comment: I don't remember installing, but I may have. Just type Tweak in dash and its setting is there.